# ObjectSet's Where() method and memory

Tags: c#, database, memory-management, entity-framework-4, objectset

I'm using an ObjectSet's methods to do various queries in a table, namely, selecting a few records from it as such:

```
    var results = Repository.Find(c => c.Enabled == 1).ToList();
```

Here is the Find method of my repository:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        try
        {
            return _objectSet.Where<T>(predicate);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Now, if there is about 1,000,000 records in the targeted table, I can see the process's memory usage grow quite a lot even if the *Find* call I'm doing should return a few records at most.

It seems all the records are pulled client side, then filtered. This is obviously not what I want LINQ to do.

Do you see anything obviously wrong with what I'm doing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use IEnumerable<T> it is pulling every datarow at once into memory instead you should use IQueryable<T>

Comment: Your `Find` method accomplishes nothing productive at all.  Why are you not just using `Where` directly on the `Repository`?

Comment: @MUG4N He's only using that for his output, which should already be filtered, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead of a plain `Func<T, bool>`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
  // your code
}
```

`Where` is overloaded (see [ObjectSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx)), and the `Func<T>`-overload is defined by `IEnumerable<T>`, whereas `Expression<TDelegate>` is used by `IQueryable<T>`. Because `predicate` is a `Func<T>` the compiler invokes the extension method defined for `IEnumerable<T>`, which in turn fetches all the records and does LINQ to objects.

Comment: From which namespace is Expression ? System.Linq.Expressions ?

Comment: Then I must be doing something wrong because I get this: The non-generic type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' cannot be used with type arguments
Using the generic type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<TDelegate>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: I see. Excuse me, I was wrong. Basically it's an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead of an `Expression<T, bool>`. I edited my answer, and I'll double-check.

Comment: Right, I found another example through Google that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Now it should be right, isn't it? I double-checked on my Visual Studio 2012 installation.

Comment: Yes it is. Windows Task Manager also shows the process not growing to an outrageous size! Kudos.